# Bash Script move a file to desktop

Tags: linux, shell

Hello guys i am doing a very simple script that works like an installation script, i have been successful to create a launcher for the application but how could i code the command to move the launcher to the desktop , because mi path to the desktop is /home/cendit/Escritrio but no the case for other users that would like to use the script, for now i have left the launcher in the same folder of the application them the user must copy manually to the desktop.

Here my script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Añadiendo sotfware necesario...\n"                            #Mostrar mensaje
apt-get install g++ libusb-1.0-0-dev libgtk-3-dev

echo "Añadiendo repositorios...\n"                                  #Mostrar mensaje
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
apt-get update
apt-get install vlc libvlc-dev

shopt -s xpg_echo
echo "Para la instalación TDA LINUX debe ser super usuario."    #Mostrar mensaje

mkdir -p /opt/TDA_LINUX                             #Crea la carpeta TDA_LINUX

echo "Compilando...\n"                                  #Mostrar mensaje
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -lusb-1.0 -lvlc -pthread -rdynamic -lX11 -s `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -o tda_executable -w #Compilae el código fuente y crea el ejecutable

mv tda_executable /opt/TDA_LINUX            #mueve el ejecutable a la carpeta TDA_LINUX 
cp logo.png /opt/TDA_LINUX                  #mueve el ejecutable a la carpeta TDA_LINUX 

echo "Creando acceso directo...\n"                  #Mostrar mensaje
touch /opt/TDA_LINUX/TDA.desktop                    #crea el archivo del lanzador en la carpeta TDA_LINUX llamado TDA
shopt -s xpg_echo
echo "[Desktop Entry]\nVersion=0.1\nName=TDA_LINUX\nComment=Televisión Digitla Abierta Venezolana\nExec=/opt/TDA_LINUX/tda_executable\nIcon=/opt/TDA_LINUX/logo.png\nTerminal=false\nType=Application\nCategories=Utility;Application;" > /opt/TDA_LINUX/TDA.desktop

chmod 755 /opt/TDA_LINUX/TDA.desktop                #Hacer el launcher ejecutable

echo "Copindo regla udev...\n"                  #Mostrar mensaje
cp -R 40_usb.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/           #Mover las reglas udev al sistema

sudo udevstart                                  #Comenzar las reglas
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d say just use

```
cp (filename) ~/Desktop
```

and that should work for the majority of people. It puts the file into the directory Desktop found in their home directory.